# MacOS Image Capture app squatting on USB device while trying to use xsane

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, libusb, image-scanner, sane

I had a new machine set up running **El Capitan**, and **xsane** installed for the scanner via macports as usual. xsane failed to recognise the device, with the following symptoms:

```
sane-find-scanner
```

> found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0128 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:020:026

```
scanimage -L
```

> No scanners were identified.

Even as root I got

```
# /opt/local/bin/scanimage -T -d epson2:libusb:020:026
```

> scanimage: open of device epson2:libusb:020:026 failed: Access to resource has been denied

The MacOS tools for this scanner worked, so I observed that when I connect the USB cable, there was some process starting:

```
tail /var/log/system.log
```

> Nov 23 23:01:47 host kernel[0]: 348238.593685 EPSON Scanner@14200000: AppleUSBDevice::waitForInterfacesGated: timeout waiting for _interfacesMatched
>
> Nov 23 23:01:47 host EPSON Scanner[86324]: --> HandleMessageFromICDD
>
> Nov 23 23:01:47 host EPSON Scanner[86322]: --> HandleMessageFromICDD
>
> Nov 23 23:01:47 host EPSON Scanner[86323]: --> HandleMessageFromICDD

It turned out that this process was squatting on the USB device so libusb did not get access. (In some cases, the process was even started in the name of a background user, not active with fast user swapping):

```
ps aux | grep EPSON
```

> username 86323 0.1  0.1 2582644  22072 ??  S 11:01pm 0:00.21
>   /Library/Image Capture/Devices/EPSON Scanner.app/Contents/MacOS/EPSON
>   Scanner

Now once I kill the `Image Capture` process, sane runs nicely, and I can use xsane again:

```
scanimage -L
```

> device `epson2:libusb:020:026' is a Epson GT-X700 flatbed scanner

While I have my workaround, remains the question what would prevent that Image Capture from occupying the USB device without asking?

For other libusb issues, there are some hints to unload a kernel extension, however for this problem *kextstat* shows no difference in the extensions before and after plugging the scanner in.

Comment: Have found a solution for that, I am facing the same issue with a canon scanner.

Comment: So what is your solution then? As said, currently I am killing the Epson app before starting xsane, an alias works for me: `xsane.kill_epson is aliased to killall EPSON\ Scanner; xsane`